# Library to evaluate numerical expressions

Tags: c#

is there a .NET library that can perform a numerical operation and return a value?

I have an expression like so:

1 + 1/2

this should return the double equivalent of the same.
I wont be passing a string, it will be a numeric value and the return should be a numeric.

Comment: How will "1 + 1/2" be passed as a numeric value?

Comment: @SWeko make the param as a double, pass 1 + 1/2, C# will evaluate it as 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) for medium-to-complex calculations and it seems that it will fit your needs.

---

About the OP's comment on the original question:

```
double d = 1/2;
```

will return 0 in c#, because the integer 1 is divided by the integer 2, resulting in an integer result of 0.

If you need to trigger real-number mathematics, at least one of the operands must be defined as a real number. You can do that by specifying it with a decimal point (1.0 instead of 1), or by adding a type specifier after the value (1f or 1d instead of 1).
Take a look at this example:

```
double d1 = (1 + 1/2); //returns 1
double d2 = (1 + 1.0/2); //returns 1.5
double d3 = (1 + 1/2.0); //returns 1.5
double d4 = (1 + 1f/2); //returns 1.5
double d5 = (1 + 1d/2); //returns 1.5
```

Comment: NCalc is so easy to set up given what it can do

Answer (score 0):

See here [CodeDom Calculator - Evaluating C# Math Expressions Dynamically](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx)